# Endless loop on boot after reflashing ESP-12E with AT firmware

Tags: esp8266

I flashed the ESP-12E from AT firmware 2.0 (running ok) to NodeMCU (running ok). When I reflashed it back to the AT 2.0 it is stuck in endless loop on boot:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x40100000, len 2408, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0xe5
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0x84
load 0x3ffe8310, len 632, room 0 
tail 8
chksum 0xd8
csum 0xd8

2nd boot version : 1.6
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : QIO
  SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
no GPIO select!
jump to run user1 @ 1000

rf_cal[0] !=0x05,is 0xFF
```

I am sure I flashed it correctly, it was not my first flashing of AT firmware. Just to be sure:

```
esp_init_data_default.bin -> 0x3fc000
blank.bin -> 0x3fe000
boot_v1.6.bin -> 0x0000
user1.1024.new.2.bin -> 0x1000
blank.bin -> 0x7e000
```

I can even reflash it to the NodeMCU firmware and it works, but reflashing to the AT firmware ends in the same endless loop again.

I suspect the problem is in initialization data, but I'm at my wit's end with it.

Comment: `rf_cal` is radio-frontend calibration data. The bootloader sees that this is erased flash data (after erasing a flash sector, the data in it becomes  `0xff 0xff 0xff ...`). Can you do a `esptool.py erase_flash` and reflash? It may be that you're flashing `esp_init_data_default.bin` to the wrong address thus only reading erased flash contents. The `8 mbit` (1 MByte) message seems like it's not using your flash fully. This value is set by `esptool.py` during flashing (`--flash_size`). What exactly is your flash command? Can you flash default data to `0xfc000`?

Comment: Maximilian, thanks for you reply. I did erasing of the flash in past. I made some new tests, read the whole 4M flash and compared it with one in a functional module and finally got it working. The critical is your last sentence.  

**The solution:** I had to flash `esp_init_data_default.bin` to the address `0xfc000`. I found nothing about it in the documentation but this is the way I got the ESP12 to work again.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full answer and writeup to the comments:

The error message is due to the bootloader trying to read the contents of its radio-frontend calibration data (hence the name `rf_cal`). It compares it with a magic number, `0x05`, but fails because it reads `0xFF` at that point. `0xff` is an indication that you read data from flash which was erased. After erasing a flash-sector, the data in it becomes `0xff 0xff 0xff..`. Hence it seems as if the bootloader is trying to access the data from the wrong address, thus only reading erased flash data. The RF-calibration data is stored in the file `esp_init_data_default.bin` and must be flashed to the correct address in order for the bootloader to be able to read it.

The [NodeMCU documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/flash/#sdk-init-data)  tells us the needed address for `esp_init_data_default.bin` given the size of the flash of our ESP module:

[image: flash addresses]

The bootloader messages

```
2nd boot version : 1.6
SPI Speed      : 40MHz
SPI Mode       : QIO
SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
```

indicate that the flashed firmware (or that what is overriden by `esptool.py`) uses the 8 MBit flash size. There should be two ways to fix this:

- Put `esp_init_data_default.bin` to the address the 8Mbit (1 MByte) bootloader expects, which is `0xfc000`
- Force the usage of the 32 MBit (4 MByte) Flash map by giving `esptool.py` the parameter `--flash_size 32m`. This makes `esptool.py` overwrite a few bytes in the firmware (at `0x000000`) to adapt the firmware.

By your comments, method one worked. If there are problems however with the flash or the firmware, consider also trying method 2.